# В каком роде правильно употреблять названия фирм, компаний и брендов?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно написать?

Samsung *сделал* планшет.

Samsung *сделала* планшет.

Android *обогнала* iOS.

Android *обогнал* iOS.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы не гадать, правильно употреблять название как приложение: фирма Samsung выпустила планшет, бренд Samsung известен во всём мире.

Answer (score 1):

Совершенно согласен, что для грамотного построения предложения лучше употреблять дополнительные слова, понятные для склонения (фирма, компания, бренд) + наименование. Однако, рискну предположить, что в ряде случаев и иностранные названия уже приобрели свой род, воспринимаемый всеми одинаково. Нет же разногласий, что "Форд" выпустил (а не выпустила) новую модель, а "Шанель" представил**А** новый аромат? В ряде случаев это признается от происхождения названия (особенно, когда оно от фамилии и пола создателя фирмы), но есть и изначально непереводимые наименования, воспринимаемые на русский слух однозначно как мужские (женские). Тот же "Samsung" скорее "мальчик" )), и то, что он чего-то там сдел**ал** никому слух не режет.

Comment: > Совершенно согласен, что для грамотного построения предложения лучше употреблять дополнительные слова, понятные для склонения (фирма, компания, бренд) + наименование.
А какая в том нужда? Если автору текста известен род родового понятия, его вовсе не обязательно включать в текст, чтобы согласовать с ним в роде имя собственное.

Answer (score 0):

Род несклоняемых имен собственных определяется по роду нарицательного существительного, выступающего в роли родового понятия. Таким образом, названия фирм, компаний, операционных систем будут иметь женский род, названия брендов - мужской.